# jquery datepicker returns wrong year when using date format without year part

Tags: jquery-ui-datepicker

I use jquery datepicker (v1.8.20) with the date format set to 'D MM d' which looks like: 'Wed September 12'. When I select different year than the current one from a calendar, the getDate method returns me current year. Moreover, when I open calendar again, both selected day and month are preserved, but the year is changed for the current one. Generally it looks like year is set to current one when the date format does not contain it. Any idea how to fix that?

Comment: please provide us the code which creates the datepicker so we can take a look at it.

Answer (score 3):

Datepicker stores value only in input element, so if you don't have a year in format string, datepicker merely doesn't store it. [Here](http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/7759) one of jquery.ui developers says, that this is not a bug and "Datepicker is only designed to pick a full date".

Anyway, I had the same problem in my project, and solved it by ugly trick, that forces datepicker to store full date:

```
(function($) {
    $.datepicker._selectDateParent = $.datepicker._selectDate;
    $.datepicker._adjustInstDateParent = $.datepicker._adjustInstDate;
    $.datepicker._adjustInstDate = function(inst, offset, period) {

        var fullDate = inst.input.data('fullDate');
        if(fullDate && !period) {
            inst.drawYear = inst.currentYear = fullDate.getFullYear();
        }

        this._adjustInstDateParent(inst, offset, period);
    };
    $.datepicker._selectDate = function(id, dateStr) {
        var target = $(id);
        var inst = this._getInst(target[0]);
        var date = this._daylightSavingAdjust(new Date(inst.currentYear, inst.currentMonth, inst.currentDay));
        inst.input.data('fullDate', date);

        this._selectDateParent(id, dateStr);
    }
})(jQuery);
```

I've tested it only with datepicker 1.9.0+ and I'm not sure, that this is a good solution, but it works for me :)

Comment: This was driving me crazy until I came across with this answer. There still is one little piece missing: `setDate` method. `$.datepicker._setDateParent = $.datepicker._setDate; $.datepicker._setDate = function (inst, date, noChange) { inst.input.data('fullDate', date); this._setDateParent(inst, date, noChange); };`